# How listen the arrival of the message on the inboud-endpoint in mule esb 3.9 without explicit code?

Tags: java, mule, spring-aop, mule-studio, mule-esb

I have the classic AOP requirement: Intercept some event and modify o audit it.

## < custom-processor >

- https://gist.github.com/cmordue/4552292

Works very well but I need to insert directly into flow. This is what I don't want due to my dozens of flows

```
<flow>
  <some-inboud/>
  <custom-processor class="org.acme.Audit" />   
  <logic>
</flow>
```

## Mule Server Notifications

- **MessageProcessorNotificationListener**
- https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/cdd235f9b723074e54af27b3639ca59e#file-notificator-java

Works very well because I don't need to add it to all flows.

```
public class Auditor MessageProcessorNotificationListener<MessageProcessorNotification>{
  @Override
  public void onNotification(MessageProcessorNotification notification) {
    MuleEvent ev = notification.getSource();
    MuleMessage msg = ev.getMessage();
    Object payload = msg.getPayload();
    System.out.println("auditor");
    //etc
  }
}
```

I just need to add as spring bean and register it as notification:

When I run this project my auditor catch any step of the flow: transformers, components, scripts and the final outbound event.

## The problem

My audit logic need just catch the **initial event**, when a message arrive to flow using the inbound(http, jms, etc).

Mule Server Notification documentation says that we can configure any type of listener for different events but just **MessageProcessorNotificationListener** works.

## Attempts

I read the documentation to enable notifications just for connector events with no luck:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/notifications-configuration-reference#notification-types

```
ASYNC-MESSAGE ,CONNECTION ,CONNECTOR-MESSAGE ,CONTEXT ,CUSTOM ,EXCEPTION ,EXCEPTION-STRATEGY ,EXTENSION ,MANAGEMENT ,MESSAGE-PROCESSOR ,PIPELINE-MESSAGE ,ROUTING ,SECURITY ,TRANSACTION
```

In permutations with

- org.mule.api.context.notification.ConnectorMessageNotificationListener

  org.mule.api.context.notification.ConnectionNotificationListener

Also some post says that Mule Server Notifications works just in Anypoint Studio and not in mule standalone server :s

## Workaround

Use **MessageProcessorNotificationListener** and perform my audit just for the first invocation with a global boolean variable **isFirsTime**

## Question

How listen the arrival of the message on the inboud-endpoint in mule esb **without explicit code** and or with Mule Server Notification approach?

Comment: What do you mean by without explicit code?

Comment: I mean manually insertion. For example <custom-interceptor> will work if we insert this tag inside of the flow. In the order hand, Mule server notification is a kind of "global" listener and works without flow modification.

Comment: Your link to the docs for notifications is for Mule 4.3. This is the correct one for 3.9: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/notifications-configuration-reference